# Taylor polynomial for $f(x, y) = \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$

Tags: limits, analysis, taylor-expansion

Given the function $f(x, y) = \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ defined for $(x,y)$ with $x>0$, how can we find Taylor polynomial in point $x_0=0$? As I understood, Taylor polynomials for $n=1$ for functions with two variables are the same as tangent plane, right?

In addition, how can we prove that $f$ doesn't have a limit value in point $x_0 (0, 0)$?

Comment: The Taylor polynomial at what point? The function is not defined where $x = 0$.

Comment: At point $x_0=0$. Thank you for the answer, I didn't think about domain of the function at all!

Comment: The function isn't even defined where $x_0 = 0$, so there is no Taylor polynomial there of any order.

Comment: The given function can be analytically extended to a function also defined where $x=0 \wedge y \ne 0$, as long as you still take a domain with a branch cut (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (x, 0) \mid x \le 0 \}$).  However, the discontinuity at $(0, 0)$ is not removable, so there is no function which is analytic at $(0, 0)$ and which extends $f$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You're right, of course---I mean (and should have said) at $x_0 = (0, 0)$.